# (C++) Array as member of struct: how to get its size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, sizeof

I have a struct which has a pointer to array as a member and I'd like to determine the size of this array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[]={1,2,3,4,5};

struct myStruct {
    int *array;
};

struct myStruct my_struct={.array=array};

int main() {
    printf("A: %d\n",sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)); // this works
    printf("B: %d\n",sizeof(my_struct.array)/sizeof(*my_struct.array)); // this doesn't work
}
```

This prints:

```
A: 5
B: 2
```

I expected:

```
A: 5
B: 5
```

When I use the `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` method on the array directly it works, but it doesn't work when used on the member of `myStruct`. At first I thought that I can't assign a pointer to an array member like this, but indexing `my_struct.array[i]` returns the correct values. But as I'd like to iterate over this array, I need to know its size.

Can anybody explain to me why my attempt doesn't work and how I could implement it instead?

Comment: First array that you declare globally is **statically** allocated , thus when you call `sizeof(array)` it gives you the number of bytes it uses totally .
The array inside your struct though isn't really an array , it's just a pointer , so `sizeof(struct.array)` just gives you the size of the pointer which seems to be 4 in your computer and thus 4 / 2 = 2 .
Change `int *array` to `int array[5]` from inside your struct and you will see the desired results.

Comment: @fvalasiad hmm, I see. I actually would like to have this array to be of variable size. Is there a way around it or is it generally not possible in C++?

Comment: Do you wish to use a dynamic array? If that's the case use `std::vector`. Unless you mean that you want to create a dynamic array yourself, if that's the case you should add a `size_t size` property inside your struct to hold the array's size and dynamically reallocate memory accordingly.

Comment: @fvalasiad the array won't change during runtime, but I want to have several instances of this struct, each with arrays of different size. But including the `size` property will work for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array) the compiler does not know that `int* array` points to an array of type int and as such sizeof() only returns the size of the pointer.

So either use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or add a size member to your struct.

Comment: `int* array` is never an array. It’s a pointer. It points at an `int`. That `int` might be the first element in an array of `int`, but, as this answer suggests, it is still just a pointer. +1.